# How to create a GitHub workflow file that publishes my repository to npm?

Tags: github, npm, github-actions

I have a Stencil.js project that consists of just 1 component. A feedback widget. I have deployed it to my GitHub repository, and now I need to have it on npm, so that I can be able to install it, and have that component available anywhere.

First I had this in my workflow:

```
name: "publish npm"

on: push

jobs:
    publish:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v2
            - name: node
              uses: actions/setup-node@v2
              with:
                  node-version: 12
                  registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org
            - name: publish
              run: npm publish --access public
              env:
                  NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.IFX_FEEDBACK_WIDGET}}
```

With this, when I push my changes to my repository, I can see in Actions, and this works, and it's published to my npm registry, but what is being published is only a package json file, README, and License. The dist and loader folders are missing, and so nothing gets installed.

I then realized that I need to build this, But no matter what I try, I either get this error: npm ERR! 404 'widget-feedback@0.0.8' is not in this registry. Or You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 2, it's always some random line, and there's nothing wrong with the line.

I know I must first run npm install, and then build, but I don't know how.

I tried this:

```
name: "publish npm"

on: push

jobs:
    publish:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v2
            - name: node
              uses: actions/setup-node@v2
              with:
                  node-version: 12
                  registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org
           - name: Build library
              run: |
                npm ci
                npm run build
```

and instantly got the same error:

```
 Check failure on line 6 in .github/workflows/publish.yml

GitHub Actions
/ .github/workflows/publish.yml
Invalid workflow file
You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 6
```

This is what my repo looks like: Note that the `.npmrc` file is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your library before you can publish. Otherwise, all you are doing is push the files from your repository (that are allowed by `.npmignore`) to npm registry.

```
- name: checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: node
  uses: actions/setup-node@v2
  with:
    node-version: 12
    registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org
- name: Build library
  run: |
    npm ci
    npm run build
```

This assumes you have a `package-lock.json` file. If you instead have a `yarn.lock` file, use yarn to install and build like:

```
- name: Build library
  run: |
    yarn install --frozen-lockfile
    yarn build
```

This also assumes that you have a `build` script in your `package.json` file, like:

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "..."
}
```

---

If you don't have either `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` file committed to your GitHub repository, you can use:

```
- name: Build library
  run: |
    npm install
    npm run build
```

or

```
- name: Build library
  run: |
    yarn install
    yarn build
```

but its better to have the lock files in your repository to lock down the versions to use.

---

Once you build your library, this should generate the `dist` directory before you publish to npm registry.

Comment: In my github repository, I have a `package-lock.json` file. I just included `- name: Build library
  run: |
    npm ci
    npm run build` like you told me, and I still got the same error:  `You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 6`

Comment: I've updated my question for more clarity. Please check it out.

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, I used npm publish from my terminal instead, and it worked. It got published to npm, and now in the CODE section, I can see the dist and loader folders. I also created a CDN using the npm package, and it works, but one problem I have now is the images that I used are not included. I have an assets folder in the src/ folder, and it's apparently not in dist. Why is it not being included when I build?

Comment: @happy_story `name` and `run` ought to have same spaces before. You have other spaces issue in your yml as well. Look at my answer again. Y

Comment: I really don't see a difference? I just copied your cod, I did not write it myself. Could you please tell me where exactly is the space issue? But also, if there's an issue with the space, then shouldn't the npm publish also not work?

Comment: In the question, both `name: Build library` and `run: |` are not in the same vertical line. Thats a yml formatting issue. Will affect only GitHub Actions.

Comment: I fixed this last night, and it worked in the sense that, no errors were shown, but when I push my changes, they're not getting published to npm. Only npm publish works.

Comment: Then please update the code in your question, and the issue you are facing.